# How to inform Crawler on AngularJS permanently moved page without losing SEO ranking

Tags: seo, javascript, laravel

I am using Angular JS app and serving snapshots for crawlers when they visit. Changes are inevitable and hence certain pages are to be moved permanently (Redirect 301).

For example:

```
www.domain.com/#!/about-us
```

change to

```
www.domain.com/#!/about-domain
```

As normal redirection can be done at the server or using mod_rewrite. What would be the best solution for Angular JS so the page ranking in SERP of old page (/about-us) can be passed onto the new page(/about-domain).

**Attempt** to redirect using laravel and htaccess however failed as server does not accept '#' and anything beyond that symbol.

**Question**
What is the best way to redirect 301, Angular JS permanently moved pages without losing the SERP ranking?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Additional Info: Using
-Laravel as backend
-Htaccess apache mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there doesn't seem to be a method to do this.

If you don't need to support older browsers, you could change the full path in javascript and not just the hash.

```
history.pushState({}, "", "/foo/bar/new-url")
```

will change the url to `<old-domain>/foo/bar/new-url` without going to a new webpage.

If you serve your one page for every url and then change what you show based on the url, this will work while preserving your SEO rankings.

You can use `history.pushState` on all modern browsers

[image]
(http://caniuse.com/#search=history.pushState)